# When can we differentiate a first order optimality condition?

Tags: derivatives, optimization

I have a doubt concerning [this handout](http://home.cerge-ei.cz/petrz/fm/f400n03.pdf), footnote 3.

> The envelope theorem applies to the problem of examining how the maximized value of the objective function and thefcontrol variable change when one of the model’s parameters changes. In our context, define $f(A,W_0) = \mathbb{E}[U(\tilde{W})]$ so that $v(W_0) =\max f(A,W_0)$ is the maximized value of the objective function when the control
> variable, $A$, is optimally chosen. Then applying the chain rule, we have
> $$\frac{dv(W_0)}{d W_0} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial A} \frac{\partial A}{\partial W_0} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_0}$$
> But since $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}(A, W_0) = 0$$
> from the first order condition, this simplifies to just
> $$\frac{dv}{dW_0}(W_0) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial W_0}(A,W_0)$$
> Again applying the chain rule to the first order condition, one obtains
> $$\frac{\partial}{\partial W_0}\frac{\partial f(A, W_0)}{\partial A} = 0 = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial A^2}(A, W_0) \frac{\partial A}{\partial W_0}(W_0) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{
> \partial A \partial W_0}(A, W_0).$$

The authors differentiate a first-order optimality condition of the type $\frac{\partial f(A, W)}{\partial A} = 0$ and get $\frac{\partial^2 f(A, W)}{\partial W \partial A} = \frac{\partial}{\partial W} \frac{\partial f(A, W)}{\partial A} = 0$.

However, I don't get why we are allowed to say that at a point where a function (let's call $g(A, W) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$) is zero, its derivative is zero too. I can think of a trivial example where this is not true: when $\sqrt{x} = 0$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sqrt{x}$ is not even defined (or is infinite if we only think about the right derivative).

What are the conditions for "differentiating both sides of an equation" this way?

Furthermore, how do the authors invoke the envelope theorem but then disregard that when the FOC is verified, the first term on the RHS of the first equation is zero? If they take that into account, the substitution between $\frac{\partial f}{\partial W_0}$ and $\frac{dv}{dW_0}$ would not be useful, would it?

Answer (score 1):

For each $W_0$, the optimality condition only holds for particular values of $A^*$ (the maximizers). The partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}(A^*,W_0)=0$ for all $W_0$. Another way to see it is to consider the right hand side a function of $W_0$, $\mathrm{zero}(W_0)\equiv 0$; if two functions are equal then certainly their derivatives are equal, and the derivative of the constantly $0$ function $\mathrm{zero}$ is $0$ too.

Comment: So this is a consequence of the fact that we are differentiating the FOC for $A$ wrt $W$, and it wouldn't be possible to do this if we were again differentiating wrt $A$, right?

Comment: It would be possible but it wouldn't be interesting. Since we evaluated the FOC at the point $A$, it is now a constant with respect to this variable. Differentiating both sides here would just give you $0=0$ the same way if you differentiated the equation $10=5*2$ with respect to $x$.